# Como adicionar um tamanho de imagem para determinado tipo de media no wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnail

Na hora de inserir um post posso selecionar algumas imagens para incluir, como imagem de destaque, imagens no corpo do post e também por campos criados por plugins (ex.: Advanced Custom Fields). Essas imagens podem ser redimensionadas com a função `add_image_size` no arquivo `functions.php` do tema, por exemplo.

Porém, como posso adicionar diferentes e determinados (no plural) tamanhos para a imagem de destaque, para imagens do corpo da página e para as imagens desses novos campos criados?

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem. O nome que você deu em `add_image_size` não serve pra vc referenciar o tamanho?

Comment: Exato, porém eu preciso gerar 3 tamanhos para a imagem de destaque, 4 para as imagens de corpo e 2 para as inseridas pelo plugin. Quando uso essa função, ele geraria 9 imagens, além das já padronizadas para cada imagem adicionada

Comment: O que vc quer é gerar os tamanhos somente quando forem usados nos campos específicos?

Comment: Isso, para que não sejam geradas imagens desnecessárias

Comment: Até onde eu sei isso não é possível no server-side sem um bocado de dor de cabeça. Talvez o Photon te resolva: https://jetpack.com/support/photon/